# Link objects as fields in UML diagram

Tags: .net, visual-studio, class, uml

I'm trying to generate a diagram for a design document. I've generated a class diagram in VS. At the moment it's just a bunch of unconnected boxes as there isn't any inheritance going on. It feels like it would be more useful if I could show how the objects interact through properties and parameters.

As an example, a `Boy` class has a method `Kiss` which takes a `Girl` object. How can I show that `Boy` and `Girl` interact by connecting this in the diagram?

Is there a notation for this in UML? Or is there another type of diagram that shows this? Can I make VS draw this connection for me somehow? Or is this a silly/useless idea?

It just doesn't feel like a proper diagram unless it's got some lines on it somewhere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies other than inheritance is usually generated for links (instances of associations). There two types of associations: composition and aggregation.
If your Girl object would be a member of your `Boy` class you would give VS a change to detect this association.

Maybe this helps [UML-Class-Diagram](http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/2206791/The-UML-Class-Diagram-Part-1.htm)